# the date return undefined in form angular 4

Tags: forms, angular, date, typescript

i have the date field in my form i want to pass it to API

component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="addMeetingForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(t)" #t="ngForm">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- first Row data -->
                    <div class="form-group" class="col-lg-5 ">
                        <ul class="flex-outer">
                            <!-- first Element -->
                            <li>
                                <label for="date"> 
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg"></i>  
                               date
                                <span style="color: red"> * </span>
                                </label>
                                <input type="date" formControlName="date" [(ngModel)]="date" >
                            </li>
```

component.ts:

```
 ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.date);
    this.addMeetingForm= new FormGroup({

        'date' : new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
```

the date always log undefined , i want to choose date form the calendar then pass it to api

dataStorage.service.ts:

```
storeMeeting(meeting){
        let url = 'http://api.azharcouncil.com/api/MainCouncils/PostMainCouncil?place='+meeting.place+'&number='+meeting.number+'&type='+meeting.kind
        +'&date='+meeting.date+'&time='+meeting.time+'&description='+meeting.description+'&file='+meeting.file+'&notes'+meeting.notes+'&user_Id='+15;
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 
        return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(meeting), options);

    }
```

Comment: Why have you  [(ngModel)]="date"  ?

Comment: i tried to use it to pass date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the [(ngModel)]

Here is a structure:

```
<form [formGroup]="model" (ngSubmit)="send(model.value)" #f="ngForm" novalidate">

<input name="name" formControlName="name">

<input name="email" formControlName="email">

<input name="fonction" formControlName="fonction">

<textarea name="message" formControlName="message"></textarea>

<button [disabled]="!model.valid">SEND</button>

</form>
```

and

```
this.model = fb.group({
    name: [null, Validators.required],
    message: [null],
    email: [null, Validators.email],
    fonction: [null, Validators.compose([YourCustomValidator, Validators.required])]
})
```

More here: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: my problem is passing date , it passed it with undefined , i want to pass the date i chose to api .

Comment: Yes, but you don't need your ngModel. try <input type="date" formControlName="date" formControlName="date">

Comment: Have you write your form with the structure i give you? Don't forget: 
(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(t.value)"